# How to fix : LINK Error when using Try_Run command in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2

I am working on setting up a project folder architecture for a game and want to compile and link dependencies while keeping a clean project structure using CMake.

This imply that external libraries are built separately from my application binary. The application binary should however be able to access includes & sources files when building.

Here is a link to the git project : https://github.com/guyllaumedemers/SDL2-Tetris.

Here's my project folder architecture :

```
cmake
doc
extern
 - libImGUI
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - @git.submodule - imgui
   - libImGUI.cpp
 - libSDL2
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - @git.submodule - sdl2
   - libSDL2.cpp
 - CMakeLists.txt
src
 - appTetris
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - Main.cpp
 - CMakeLists.txt
test
CMakeLists.txt
```

Before integrating the libraries I have added in my project, I want to run a test using ONLY my dummy source files with CMake Try_Run command.

```
// test script
#include <cstdio>

void libImGUITest(){ std::printf("libImGUI, Hello World!");}
```

I have created a src file under extern/libSDL2 with a simple function definition & did the same for the second library under extern/libImGUI. **You can ignore the target_include_directories** atm since I do not require the headers of the actual library.

```
project(
    libImGUI
)

# add directory for lib

add_library(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    OBJECT
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libImGUI.cpp"
)

add_library(
    lib::imgui
    ALIAS
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
)

target_include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/pkg/backends"
)

# temp solution for try_run in appTetris CMakeLists.txt

add_library(
    tryRunlibImGUI
    STATIC
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}>
)
```

Under my application folder : src/appTetris, I have my application entry point which is a Main.cpp with 2 forward declarations.

I am expecting the **LINKER** to resolve the definition of the forward declaration and print both library output message in the console log.

```
void libImGUITest();
void libSDL2Test();

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    libImGUITest();
    libSDL2Test();
    return 0;
}
```

src/AppTetris CMakeLists.txt

```
set(
    MYLANGUAGES
    CXX
)

project(
    Demo
        VERSION 0.0.0.0
        DESCRIPTION "Demo"
        LANGUAGES ${MYLANGUAGES}
)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    Main.cpp
)

add_dependencies(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    lib::imgui
    lib::sdl2
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    lib::imgui
    lib::sdl2
)

# set project specifics

set(
    MYCXX_VERSION_STANDARD
    20
)

set_property(
    TARGET
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTY
    CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD
    ${MYCXX_VERSION_STANDARD}
)

if(NOT ${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD} EQUAL ${MYCXX_VERSION_STANDARD})
    message(WARNING "WARNING! CXX_STANDARD SHOULD BE CXX_${MYCXX_VERSION_STANDARD}, CURRENTLY : ${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}")
else()
    message(WARNING "WARNING! CXX_STANDARD IS CXX_${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}")   # why this doesnt print?
endif()

set(
    CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED
    ON
)

if(${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED})
    message(WARNING "WARNING! CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED IS ${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED}. MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THE LATEST COMPILER VERSION SUPPORTING THE CURRENT REQUIREMENTS FOR CXX_${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD}")
endif()

set(
    CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS
    OFF
)

if(NOT ${CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS})
    message(WARNING "WARNING! CXX_EXTENSIONS IS ${CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS}!")
endif()

# check support for LINK Time Optimization between translation units

include(CheckIPOSupported)

check_ipo_supported(
    RESULT
    IS_IPO_SUPPORTED
    OUTPUT
    IPO_SUPPORT_LOG_OUTPUT
    LANGUAGES
    ${MYLANGUAGES}
)

if(NOT ${IS_IPO_SUPPORTED})
    message(WARNING "IPO ADD ON SUPPORTED : ${IS_IPO_SUPPORTED}. ${IPO_SUPPORT_LOG_OUTPUT}")
else()
    set(
        CMAKE_INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION
        TRUE
    )
endif()

# check compiler features supported

set(
    PRINT_UNSUPPORTED_COMPILE_FEATURES
    FALSE
)

if(${PRINT_UNSUPPORTED_COMPILE_FEATURES})
    foreach(VAR IN LISTS CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES)
        list(FIND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES ${VAR} RESULT COMPILE_FEATURE_SUPPORT_RESULT)
        if(NOT ${COMPILE_FEATURE_SUPPORT_RESULT})
            message(WARNING "WARNING! FEATURE NOT SUPPORTED : ${VAR}")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endif()

# run try catch on dependencies

set(
    APP_TETRIS_TEST_BINARY_DIR
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/test"
)

set(
    TARGET_TRY_RUN
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Main.cpp"
)

# try_run cannot use ALIAS for some reason. target_link_libraries however allow such setup
# try_run doesn't allow OBJECTlib which means I can only create another lib that capture the TARGET_OBJECTS thru transitive property

try_run(
    MAIN_CPP_RUN_RESULT
    MAIN_CPP_COMPILE_RESULT
    "${APP_TETRIS_TEST_BINARY_DIR}"
    "${TARGET_TRY_RUN}"
    LINK_LIBRARIES
    tryRunlibImGUI
    tryRunlibSDL2
    COMPILE_OUTPUT_VARIABLE
    TRY_COMPILE_LOG_OUTPUT
    RUN_OUTPUT_VARIABLE
    TRY_RUN_LOG_OUTPUT
)

if(NOT ${MAIN_CPP_COMPILE_RESULT})
    message(SEND_ERROR "SEND_ERROR! TARGET TRY COMPILATION FAILED : ${TARGET_TRY_RUN}, COMPILE OUTPUT : ${TRY_COMPILE_LOG_OUTPUT}, RUN OUTPUT : ${TRY_RUN_LOG_OUTPUT}")
elseif(NOT ${MAIN_CPP_RUN_RESULT})
    message(SEND_ERROR "SEND_ERROR! TARGET TRY RUN FAILED : ${TARGET_TRY_RUN}, COMPILE OUTPUT : ${TRY_COMPILE_LOG_OUTPUT}, RUN OUTPUT : ${TRY_RUN_LOG_OUTPUT}")
endif()
```

However, when running Try_Run command in CMake, I get the following linking error.

```
CMake Error at src/appTetris/CMakeLists.txt:138 (message):
SEND_ERROR! TARGET TRY COMPILATION FAILED :
D:/VisualStudio/SDL2/SDL2-GameDevCMake/SDL2-Tetris/src/appTetris/Main.cpp,
COMPILE OUTPUT : Change Dir:
D:/VisualStudio/SDL2/SDL2-GameDevCMake/SDL2-Tetris/out/build/bin/SDL2-TetrisApp/test/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual
Studio/2022/Enterprise/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe
cmTC_4786f.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64
/p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /v:m && MSBuild version 17.3.1+2badb37d1 for
.NET Framework

Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.33.31629 for x64
Main.cpp
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
cl /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_4786f.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_4786f.dir\Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W1 /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "D:\VisualStudio\SDL2\SDL2-GameDevCMake\SDL2-Tetris\src\appTetris\Main.cpp"

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'tryRunlibImGUI.lib'
[D:\VisualStudio\SDL2\SDL2-GameDevCMake\SDL2-Tetris\out\build\bin\SDL2-TetrisApp\test\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_4786f.vcxproj]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to compile and run the Try_Run command?

Comment: What is a **purpose** of `try_run` in your code? If you want to test whether you application/library works, then use `add_test` functionality instead. The function `try_run` (and `try_compile`) is intended to be used for **introspection** purposes, when a project wants to determine abilities of the platform where it is built, and according to determined abilities use one or another configurations.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that instead. I feel like I was misunderstanding the purpose of the try_run command. Thanks for clarifying that up!